# Number of positive integers $a,b$ such that $4a+6b=k$

Tags: number-theory

I am studying modular forms for $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ at the moment, I have proven that $M_k$ has as basis (for even $k$) $\{E_4^aE_6^b\,\,\colon\,4a+6b=k\}$. This shows that the number of $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $4a+6b=k$ equals $\lfloor k/12 \rfloor$ if $k\equiv 2\mod (12)$ and $\lfloor k/12 \rfloor +1$ if $k\not\equiv 2\mod (12)$. I wondered whether there were more elementary proofs showing the same result

Comment: We first need to know how **you** proved the "result" before we can think about finding a "more elementary proof". Please tell us how your proof goes.

Comment: I have used various results of modular forms, such as the valence formula and the fact that $\dim(M_k)=\dim(M_{k-12})+1$. But this requires quite some techniques from complex analysis, whereas I think there must be a more number theoretical approach. Yet I haven't been able to find it

Answer (score 2):

This is [OEIS sequence A103221](https://oeis.org/A103221) "Number of partitions of n into parts 2 and 3". Its ordinary
generating function (GF) is easily given by
$$f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n =
 1/(1-x^2)/(1-x^3). \tag{1} $$
Using the simple identity
$$(1-x^2)(1-x^3) = 1-x^2-x^3+x^5 \tag{2}$$
gives the recursion formula
$$a(n) = a(n-2) + a(n-3) - a(n-5) \tag{3}$$
using elementary arguments.

Now notice the identity
$$(1-x^6)f(x) = (1-x^6)/(1-x^2)/(1-x^3) =
  1/(1-x) - x. \tag{4}$$
The left side is the GF of $\,a(n)-a(n-6)\,$ while the right
side is the GF of the constant sequence $1$ *except* at $n=1$.

This implies that $\,a(n) = a(n-6)+1$ for $\,n\ge 6.\,$
Now check that $\,a(n) = 1\,$ if $\,0\le n\le 5\,$
*except* that $\,a(1)=0.\,$

Comment: @SayanDutta Thanks for that comment! I have added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-If you have a particular solution $(a_0,b_0)$ then 
$$4a+6b=k\\4a_0+6b_0=k$$ implies $4(a-a_0)+6(b-b_0)=0$ and you have the parameterization of all the solutions: $$a=a_0+6t\\b=b_0-4t$$ Now the number of positive solution depends on $k$ however as far as I know the corresponding calculation should be by brute force.